# Selenium, в чем разница между использованием приведенных выражений?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, методы

Подскажите почему в одной ситуации IDE выполняет метод click(), а в другой ругается?
В данном коде отрабатывает как надо.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SecondTestCase {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Launch the Website
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/");



    System.out.println("Successfully opened the website 
www.seleniumhq.org/docs/");


    String a = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("Title is:"+a);

    //Строка в которой используется метод click()

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='toctree-wrapper compound']/ul/li[1]/a/em")).click();

    String b = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println("New page is:"+b);
    driver.navigate().back();
    String c=driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println("New new back url:"+c);
    // Close the driver
    driver.close();

}
```

}

А вот если в конце строки что следует за комментрием (//Строка в которой используется метод click()) собственно убрать метод click() и перенести его на следующую в виде driver.click(); то получим ошибку "Cannot resolve method". Пример:

```
//Строка в которой используется метод click()

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='toctree-wrapper compound']/ul/li[1]/a/em"));
driver.click();
```

Comment: Потому, что метод `click` есть у того, что возвращает метод `findElement` а не у объекта `driver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

driver - это объект интерфейса [WebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html), который не содержит метод click().

Вы же click() вызываете после findElement, который возвращает объект [WebElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html), который содержит данный метод.

Правильно будет следующий код

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='toctree-wrapper compound']/ul/li[1]/a/em"));
element.click();
```

Если коротко, то WebDriver - интерфейс для работы с браузерами. Перейти куда-то, найти что-то, манипуляции с логами браузера.

WebElement - для работы с объектами на странице: клик, скролл, getText()